# Dark purple screen with graphic corruption at boot, using wubi

Tags: boot, wubi, screen-corruption

Decided to give Ubuntu a try using the stand alone wubi.exe. When I'm done installing, and rebooting for the first time, I only get a black screen with a blinking text input cursor, and my caps lock and scroll lock blinks.

After another reboot, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS96E.jpg) screen with image corruption.

I am using an Nvidia GeForce 580 graphics card on a ASUS P7P55D PRO motherboard running Windows 7 HP 64bit.

Comment: I've also got the same problem on a 580M

Comment: GeForce cards are notorious for their Linux compatibility.  Try instead putting the monitor into your motherboard's VGA/DVI port, remove the graphics card and boot it up again.  If that works you should be able to install the drivers from [here](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/linux-display-amd64-304.51-driver-uk.html).  If that succeeds then you should be able to reboot your computer using your graphics card as normal.  Try this and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Press up, at least that is what works for me with my WUBI. Hope it helps.